# Wordpress .htaccess Rewrite Rule for URLs after Change Root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**WordPress: 3.5.1**

How do I modify my .htaccess file to Rewrite/redirect old URL paths to the new paths after placing WordPress in its own sub-directory (using https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory -- Using a pre-existing subdirectory install )?

**The Problem**
I had an older Wordpress install in a folder called http://{www.mywebsite.com URL}/wp. I revised the website and followed the instructions for "moving" the site so now my domain uses simply http://{www.mywebsite.com URL}/ for the files. Wordpress runs everything now (unlike my old site where WP was just the bog link.) The moving instructions worked fine in general.

BUT, I want my old links (from search engines) such as http://{www.mywebsite.com URL}/wp/archives/1534 to redirect to http://{www.mywebsite.com URL}/archives/1534 . This does not occur with the default Rewrite Rules used by WordPress. In psuedo code:

> Use the general rewrite rules unless 
>   coming from a link where I want
>   to "strip" the /wp from the link.

I tried several rewrite variations citing the Apache mod-rewrite documents but none seem to work. The lines I tried in the sample .htaccess file below are prefaced by #Attempt {number}-- (and I realize that these are commented--in the real file they are uncommented.)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Attempt 1-- 
RewriteRule  ^wp/(.*)$  /$1  [L,QSA]

# Default WP ruls
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]

#Attempt 2 --
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} wp
RewriteRule (^/wp)(.*) $2 [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -- it will do a full 301 redirect (which you want, since this is a permanent change to the URL):

```
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'd also recommend putting it before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment, since I think WordPress will rewrite what's inside there if you change certain settings.

Comment: Thank you Nate. I tried this code and permutations--including re-positioning at various places in the file. Unfortunately, this did not seem to help. The re-write never seems affected. (I wish there was a way to see which rules were being applied.)

Comment: Huh. I ran your initial code through the rewrite tester here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it thinks the first attempt you have should have done the job. Are you sure you're updating the right `htaccess` file?

Comment: I have been plugging away with this again today. I am editing the / root version of .htaccess. I am also seeing the results. I tried the following and it ALMOST works RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp
RewriteRule ^/wp(.*+)$ $1 [R=301, L] The only problem is that this shortens the request URI. So if i started with http://{{www.mysite.com}}/wp/archives/news the .htaccess code here rewrites as /news (omitting not only the /wp but also the critical /archives). I tried adding lazy qualifiers to the code but that does not seem to help. Hmmmm.... So close.